# SugarCRM 7 adding PCA Predict - this.model is null on second attempt

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this, sugarcrm

To give some background, PCA Predict is a service whereby you start typing an address and it will autocomplete with suggestions and fill in the other address fields when you click on the correct address.

I'm having to do some extra work because where the fields get filled out by PCA Predict, it isn't saved to the model (it just exists in the view) (by adding a space character to the field will make it save).

I have it working on the first attempt, but if I navigate to a different module, then come back, model is null and I get an error.

```
({
     // CustomRecord View (base) 
extendsFrom: 'AccountsRecordView',
initialize: function (options) {
    this._super('initialize', [options]);

},

render: function(){
     this._super('render');
},


editClicked: function() {
   this._super('editClicked');
   var self = this; 
   setTimeout(function() {

      pca.load();

      pca.on("load", function (type, Id, control) {
         control.listen("populate", function (address) {
             self.model.set('shipping_address_city', address.City);

             //self.model is null second time round.

         });
      });
   }, 2000);

}

})
```

Why is self.model null!?  All the other properties of self is available, all apart from model, which is set to null!

[image: Console of self object]

Comment: When you say "second time round", what do you mean? Are you wanting to save the values to the model as soon as the selection is completed? Or does the user need to click save?

Comment: @Reisclef The above code is needed the first time because when you just click the address from PCAPredict and click save, what actually gets saved will be just what you've *typed*.  Although PCAPredict will fill out all the fields, these won't get saved, since they don't exist in the model, Sugar does a change event to commit what's on the screen to the model, so when you click save it's available in the model.  The problem seems to be that pca never gets reset, so the .on event always is referencing the original model (which later isn't available).